# Why does aluminium lose its three valence electrons when the electron pair have opposite spins?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atoms

Why does aluminium lose its three valence electrons when the electron pair have opposite spins? Why do metals generally lose electrons completely instead of attaining pairs of electrons with opposite spin?

I am asking this in the context of the energetic stability of atoms. Atoms gain, lose or share electrons to have pairs of electrons of the opposite spin. Like chlorine needs one electron of opposite spin for the pair to cancel out and be stable. Aluminium has three valence electrons; it can gain an electron to cancel out the spins but it losses all three: why is that? Metals tend to lose electrons when they can conveniently gain and be stable.

Comment: It is not clear what situation one is talking about (in many chemical bonds Aluminium does not lose its electrons, also it is usually one or three, but not two, if I am not mistaken). Moreover, the question is more about chemistry than physics.

Comment: @RogerVadim Sorry wrote 2 unintentionally instead of 3.

Comment: Anyhow, please expand yoru question to describe more precisely the situation that you are talking about. It is impossoble to answer without knowing what you are referring to (ionisation, molecular bond, aluminium salt in a solution, metal, etc.)

Comment: @RogerVadim I have now mentioned what I am referring to.

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/162709/79678.

Answer (score 0):

A look at [the periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table) could explain it: the elements are arranged from left to right by the number by the number of electrons in the outer shell. Metals generally have few electrons (from one to three) and they reach a stable configuration (requiring 2 electrons in s-shell and 6 electrons in p-shell) by losing them rather than by gaining electrons. On the other hand, elements like Chlorine need only a few electrons to complete a shell and hence show acidic properties.

Comment: As a chemist, I strongly endorse looking at the periodic table! But the OP has some muddled notions about spin pairing and metals losing electrons or being able to ‘conveniently’ gain electrons and be stable.